# @apply not working in Tailwind and Angular

Tags: tailwind-css

I have installed tailwind successfully and I have implemented when I put inside `class`. The problem is that I wanted to put it in `@apply`. I don't have any idea why isnt it working

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dOg2.png
[image]

```
.active {
  @apply border-r-4 border-green-400;
}
```

**tailwind config**

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: "transparent",
      black: {
        light: "#1D1D1F",
        DEFAULT: "#000000",
      },
      white: "#fff",
    },
    extend: {
      animation: {
        // If you are using Toast component
        left: "left 0.3s",
        right: "right 0.3s",

        // if you are using the animate variant of the modal
        modal: "modal 0.3s",

        // if you are using drawer variant right
        "drawer-right": "drawer-right 0.3s",

        // if you are using drawer variant left
        "drawer-left": "drawer-left 0.3s",

        // if you are using drawer variant top
        "drawer-top": "drawer-top 0.3s",

        // if you are using drawer variant bottom
        "drawer-bottom": "drawer-bottom 0.3s",
      },
      keyframes: {
        // if you are using drawer variant right
        "drawer-right": {
          "0%, 100%": { right: "-500px" },
          "100%": { right: "0" },
        },

        // if you are using drawer variant left
        "drawer-left": {
          "0%, 100%": { left: "-500px" },
          "100%": { left: "0" },
        },

        // if you are using drawer variant top
        "drawer-top": {
          "0%, 100%": { top: "-500px" },
          "100%": { top: "0" },
        },

        // if you are using drawer variant bottom
        "drawer-bottom": {
          "0%, 100%": { bottom: "-500px" },
          "100%": { bottom: "0" },
        },

        // if you are using the animate variant of the modal
        modal: {
          "0%, 100%": { top: "-500px" },
          "100%": { top: "0" },
        },

        /* If you are using Toast component*/
        left: {
          "0%, 100%": { transform: "translateX(-100%)" },
          "100%": { transform: "translateX(0)" },
        },
        right: {
          "0%, 100%": { transform: "translateX(100%)" },
          "100%": { transform: "translateX(0)" },
        },
      },
    },
    variants: {
      /* If you are using Collapse or Accordion component*/
      transitionProperty: {
        height: "height",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ["active", "checked"],
      inset: ["checked"],
      opacity: ["disabled"],
      textColor: ["active"],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: There is a longer longer thread in the tailwind github repository about that: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/1889
Have you tried that out, it doesn't seem to be an angular problem